# Como obter o valor de um parâmetro em específico em um jointpoint em um processamento "around"?

Tags: java, orientação-a-aspectos, aspectj

Tenho o seguinte método:

```java
@RequestMapping(path = "/{tenant}/import", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<String> requisicaoImportacao(@PathVariable("tenant") String tenant,
                                                       @RequestHeader(name = "authentication") String token,
                                                       HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

  ...

  // faz lógica de negócio

  ...
}
```

Preciso fazer com que, para cada `tenant`, eu obtenha um acesso exclusivo. Só que isso também precisa ser feito em outros métodos. Para evitar alterar o código de negócio, resolvi colocar em um aspecto esse processamento.

Criei a anotação `TenantMutex` para lidar com isso. O código de negócio foi alterado apenas adicionando a notação:

```java
@RequestMapping(path = "/{tenant}/import", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
@Transactional
@TenantMutex(0)
public ResponseEntity<String> requisicaoImportacao(@PathVariable("tenant") String tenant,
                                                       @RequestHeader(name = "authentication") String token,
                                                       HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

  ...

  // faz lógica de negócio

  ...
}
```

E o processamento desse aspecto foi implementado da seguinte maneira:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class ConcurrencyAspect {

    private final HashMap<String, ReentrantLock> tenantLocks;

    public ConcurrencyAspect(@Autowired @Qualifier("tenantLocks") HashMap<String, ReentrantLock> tenantLocks) {
        this.tenantLocks = tenantLocks;
    }

    @Around(value = "@annotation(tenantMutex)")
    public Object tenantMutex(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, TenantMutex tenantMutex) throws Throwable {
        String tenant = (String) jp.getArgs()[tenantMutex.value()];
        if (tenant == null) {
            throw new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        tenant = tenant.toLowerCase();
        ReentrantLock l = tenantLocks.get(tenant);
        if (!l.tryLock(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            throw new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
        }
        try {
            return jp.proceed();
        } finally {
            l.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Eu consegui obter o valor do `tenant` fazendo a "gambiarra" de colocar, na anotação `TenantMutex`, a posição do argumento do `tenant` (no caso desse método, foi na posição 0). Porém, isso não me pareceu tão correto.

Existe alguma alternativa mais natural para obter o valor desse parâmetro dentro do processamento "ao redor" do *jointpoint*? De preferência que ele seja de algum jeito passado como argumento para o método que trata do *jointpoint*?

Comment: Achei algo relativo a isso: https://www.javainuse.com/spring/spring-boot-aop e também https://stackoverflow.com/q/5568617/4438007 ; talvez consiga usar e transformar em uma resposta

Comment: Outro ponto interessante: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators

Comment: Consegui fazer uma implementação baseada nisso: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3567170/4438007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No final das contas, usei `reflection` propriamente dito.

Anotei qual o parâmetro que eu gostaria de tratar como `@Tenant`. Para conseguir identificar (via `AspectJ`) quais os métodos que eu gostaria que tivesse isso, eu detecto essa necessidade quando quem está anotado é o método propriamente dito ou mesmo a classe (se a classe estiver anotada assim, todos os seus métodos públicos deveriam tratar essa questão do `@Tenant`).

A grosso modo, ficou assim meu código:

```java
@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Aspect
@Component
public class TenantAspect {

    // minha classe proprietária descendente de org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource
    private final TenantRoutingDataSource tenantDataSource;

    public TenantAspect(@Autowired TenantRoutingDataSource tenantDataSource) {
        this.tenantDataSource = tenantDataSource;
    }

    @Around(value = "@within(Tenant) || @annotation(Tenant)")
    public Object tenant(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        try {
            String tenant = AnnotationUtils.getSingleParamWithAnnotation(jp, Tenant.class);
            if (tenant == null) {
                throw new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
            tenant = tenant.toLowerCase();
            if (!tenantDataSource.isTenantValid(tenant)) {
                throw new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
            TenantContextHolder.setTenantId(tenant);
            return jp.proceed();
        } finally {
            TenantContextHolder.clearTenantId();
        }
    }
}
```

Explicando:

- a anotação `@Order` do Spring indica a "posição relativa" de execução dos processadores de anotação; a priori, todos os processadores tem a menor relevância possível, mas eu precisava que o `tenant` fosse setado antes de se iniciar uma transação (indicado pelo `@Transactional` do Spring)
  então, por pura conveniência, coloquei meu processador como tendo a mais alta precedência
- a anotação `@Aspect` do AspectJ é para ser tratado percebido pelo AspectJ justamente como um processador de aspecto, nada de secreto aqui
- `@Component` para permitir que o Spring faça as injeções de dependência como bem entender

Então eu mando processar ao redor da classe anotada com `@Tenant` (`@within(Tenant)`) como também dos métodos anotados (`@annotation(Tenant)`). Como se pode perceber, eu extraí a magia do processamento com `reflection` desse ponto em específico para outra classe:

```java
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getSingleParamWithAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, Class<?> annotation) {
        Signature sig = jp.getSignature();
        if (sig instanceof MethodSignature) {
            int idx = AnnotationUtils.getSingleParamIdxWithAnnotation((MethodSignature) sig, annotation);
            if (idx != -1) {
                return (T) jp.getArgs()[idx];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static int getSingleParamIdxWithAnnotation(MethodSignature methodSig, Class<?> annotation) {
        Annotation[][] annotatedParams = methodSig.getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();

        int s = annotatedParams.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            Annotation[] annotatedParam = annotatedParams[i];
            int si = annotatedParam.length;
            for (int j = 0; j < si; j++) {
                if (annotation.isInstance(annotatedParam[j])) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    ...
```

Aqui, eu verifico se o `JointPoint` *realmente* é uma chamada de método. A [documentação do Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-defn) a respeito disso diz o seguinte:

> In Spring AOP, a join point always represents a method execution

Ou seja, usando programação orientada a aspecto pelo Spring, você **sempre** terá uma execução de métodos como o `JointPoint`. Isso é indicado pelo `AspectJ` através da *assinatura* como sendo instância `MethodSignature`. Essa interface permite que você acesse o método que está no `JointPoint`, retornando um bom e velho `java.lang.reflect.Method`.

Assim, eu preciso saber quais anotações estão vinculadas a cada parâmetro. Consigo saber disso através de `getParameterAnnotations()`, que me retorna um vetor de vetores, relacionando para cada parâmetro (primeiro índice) quais anotações (vetor associado ao índice).

Logo, para saber qual o primeiro parâmetro que está anotado com a anotação específica, basta pergunta em suas anotações qual aquela que é instância da anotação:

```java
Annotation[][] annotatedParams = methodSig.getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();

int s = annotatedParams.length;
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    Annotation[] annotatedParam = annotatedParams[i];
    int si = annotatedParam.length;
    for (int j = 0; j < si; j++) {
        if (annotation.isInstance(annotatedParam[j])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
return -1;
```

Note que retorno `-1` para caso não seja possível encontrar a anotação nos parâmetros.